# How to add static method to built in class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I'd like to create a tryParse() static method for Date class. How can I do that?

```
Date.prototype.tryParse = function (value, result) {
    // ... Code ...
};
```

This adds an instance method, not a static class method. Any idea?

Comment: Yep. Sorry, I didn't remove the typings when writing the question. Correcting now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First: you really, really shouldn't. To avoid collisions and incompatibilities, it's really much, to keep that sort of method in a namespace specific to your project:

```
var myUtils = {};
myUtils.tryParseDate = function(…) {…}
```

BUT! If you really, really, want to:

```
Date.tryParse = function(…) {…}
```